# TFS Build Server stuck after warning "Cannot find the last label"

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, automated-tests

I setup an automate build on tfs server. I could not get it work because it always stuck after build source code process is completed. The processes after that is copy data from a folder to another folder which also works but it just stuck on step after that. It's like in the picture below.

I have no idea how to fix this since it does not show any error message or gives me any clue. I would like to know how can I fix this problem?

This is a proof of concept C# application. It can compile perfectly fine on my machine and it used to compile on the test server.

[image]

**Update**

After I applied parameters to MSBuild `SkipLabel and/or SkipPostBuild` the result is like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem; probably because some builds got deleted along with the label.

I fixed by following the steps [here](http://www.andygeldman.com/index.php/2011/10/ever-expanding-associated-changesets-and-work-items/) as provided by Andy Geldman for which the last good label is passed into the activity which associates work items and changesets to the build.

Comment: Article was spot on - identifiy the last good build yourself and pass this into that activity that associates the change sets. In TFS2012 and above, you need the whole IBuildDetail (not just the label).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is due to the Previous build being deleted.

Overriding MSBuild properties - `SkipLabel` and/or `SkipPostBuild` should help

[Team Foundation Build Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't have permission to edit the project file that I want to build. Can I do this in the Build Template? (Windows Workflow)

Comment: Yes the build template has a 'process tab' select this you can then supply Build Process arguments - You should see a MSBuild field. You can supply MSBuild arguments there

Comment: I set `/p:SkipLabel=true` on that field but it still continue working on this process on and on. Anything else that it might help me fix this?

Comment: Try both the SkipPostBuild and the SkipLabel arguments also run the build with verbose logging to get more information

Comment: I set log to diagnotic and it shows like in the image I posted. I tried to set both values like you suggested but it still not work.

Comment: It happens with a large project only. I tested it with two smaller projects and they work as expect. Same Build Agent and same Build controller.

Comment: I have added new image. It was captured after I applied SkipLabel and/or SkipPostBuild to the MSBuild.

Comment: Can see the image now thanks but was expecting the verbose log file section. If you are happy not worry about this build you can set the 'Associate Changesets and Work Items' property in Advanced on your build process template to false.  That may get you past the issue.

Comment: Where can I locate the verbose log file section?

Comment: on build summary screen at there top will be a link to the log